# Printers compatible with Ubuntu also compatible with Crunchbang?

Tags: printing

Would printers that are rated  compatible with Ubuntu also be compatible with Crunchbang?

Comment: How would we Ubuntu users know? Why not ask it here: http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/search/recent/

Comment: Well you never know what they changed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There both Debian based. So yes their compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Typically then yes you'll be fine.

But Crunchbang 10 is now based on directly Debian, rather than on Ubuntu. This means there may be more variability in which work than there was before.